# I need a longer 4x4 board

Tags: outdoor, television, mount

I am having trouble finding 4x4's for an outdoor project right now. I'd like to mount an outdoor television about 5.5 to 6 feet from the ground. I was planning to use two 4x4x10' pressure treated boards about 3.5 underground in cement. There is no wood available right now. My question is can I use a 4x4x8' board (I have 2 of these already) and attach a 2x4 extension on the bottom end deeper into the cement? Or could I possibly use the the 4x4x8 with 2.25 feet underground? The tv is about 95 pounds, so I worry about the strength of the supports for the tv.

Comment: "There is no wood available now?" Uh, what? Are people in your area hoarding 10, 12 and 16 foot 4x4's for covid now? Try a real lumberyard/building supply? Or use metal - conduit comes 10 (and 20 from a real electrical supply) feet long, stock, galvanized. A chunk of 2" rigid would overkill the job nicely. 2" EMT might do fine.

Comment: I was thinking conduit also because pressure treated is junk but 100 lbs is nothing I would be more concerned with wind loading.  Defiantly would not be using a spliced 4x at the ground level.

Comment: @Ecnerwal  Depending upon where you are, there is a scarcity of PT wood.   I was a Lowes yesterday and about 80% of the racks for PT wood were empty. Apparently lots of DIYers stuck at home during covid19 are installing decks, porches, etc.   Link to an article follows:  https://www.hbsdealer.com/pressure-treated-lumber-demand-spikes

Comment: Go to a real lumberyard. Many of my home derpos are way out of stock, (not as bad at Lowes, curiously), but my real dealers are fine.

Comment: And that makes total sense, since random consumers *(present company excepted, of course)* are so brand-hypnotized that they couldn’t find a real lumberyard with a seeing-eye dog.